# print Function for arrays - c++

Tags: c++, arrays

I was working on a `print()` function in C++ and was wondering:

```
template <typename BaseType>
void print(BaseType data, bool newline = false, bool raw = false) {
    // Standard > C Out
    std::cout << data;

    /* Logic
            If
                Newline is true.
    */
    if (newline)
        std::cout << std::endl;
};
```

What if this same function could react differently to arrays and print out each individual member of the array rather than give back a value like `0x22fe30`?

Something like:

```
print("Hello, World!"); // prints "Hello, World!"
print(array); // prints "[1, 0, 1]"
```

I'm only doing this for fun to see how far my skills in C++ really are and would appreciate any helpful answer. Thanks.

Comment: What you're looking for is called "specialization".

Comment: Be careful what you wish for. `"Hello, World!"` is an array of type `char[14]`

Comment: How would that work out? I'm new to C++ and self-taught, this is the first time I've heard of Specialization.

Comment: True. I didn't think about character arrays.

Comment: Self-taught is cool, but make sure you [have some good support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list). C++ is a very hard language to pick up without a good reference library.

Comment: Note, you also have to pass the size of the array. When printing a character array, the size of array can be determined by the null-terminator. But when printing array of integers, the common way to know the size is to pass the size as a separate parameter. Such a generalized print function may not be all that useful (except for learning purposes). You can make your own container, example `myvector` derived from `std::vector` and add print capabilities to it instead.

Comment: I would avoid redundant comments. Everyone who knows C++ already knows that `if(newline)` means "If newline is true"; your comment is just serving as clutter.  In this case it would be better without the comments entirely; in general, comments should add some explanation that is not immediately apparent just from the code; e.g. the rationale for why you chose to do the thing you're doing.

Comment: yes, you're right.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate into array and print them out:

```
const int arr [ 3 ] = { 5, 6, 7 };

for ( int i = 0; i < 3; i++ )

    std::cout << arr [ i ] << std::endl;
```